AWS Lambda - Can't set memory larger than 3008 MB
I'm a bit confused. In my AWS account, when I access the settings of a Lambda function to configure the maximum temporary storage, memory, and duration, the AWS console offers me to select memory sizes ranging from 128MB to 10240MB. However, when I try to set it to something like 6144MB, it throws an error, saying It can't be set higher than 3008MB. I don't understand why it offers it at the form, but won't let me apply it ... Any idea

Is this a new account? From the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html "New AWS accounts have reduced concurrency and memory quotas. AWS raises these quotas automatically based on your usage."

Yes it's a new account, opened about 4 hrs. ago.

https://repost.aws/questions/QUKruWYNDYTSmP17jCnIz6IQ/unable-to-set-lambda-memory-over-3008mb
an AWS support guy answered with this:

Lambda functions with memory configuration greater than 3GB are
currently unavailable for first time use in some regions. We are
working on restoring this feature and mitigations are in progress. If
you urgently require to use your function with memory greater than
3GB, please raise a support ticket and request that the limit get
raised for your account.



If your account quota shows 10GB, and you are getting this error, it
could be a service glitch or capacity issue.
You can either try again later, or choose another supported region and
try again.

So I believe if your account quota is 3Gb, you just need to open a support ticket, and they'll raise your limit.

So finally this is a situation know body knows what to do about it xD ... The biggest problem is that you cannot request a limit increase for memory at the AWS dashboard ...
